# Rails Couldn't find Object without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get the order of shop orders but Couldn't find Order without an ID error appear

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order without an ID)

i tried

```
 @order = Order.where("id = ? AND shop_id = ?", params[:id], @shop.id )
```

and another error

so, someone knows how to get the object from the associated objects?

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController   
  def sold
    @shop = current_user.shop
    @order =  @shop.orders.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

routes

```
resources :orders, only: [:index, :update, :destroy] do    
  member do
    get :sol
    put :sent
  end
  collection do
    match :sold
    put :sent
    match '/sold?status=paid ' => 'orders#sold', via: [:get,:put, :post], as: :shop_sold
  end
end
```

Comment: depends how is the association, you can search it by his id or the one of the associated object

Comment: thank's @FabrizioBertoglio 
the association is has_many so shop has many orders.

the associated object you mean order = Order.find(params[:id]) ?

Comment: So what's in `params[:id]`? What do you expect to be in `params[:id]` and why?

Comment: Could you show your routes, where the `sold` route is defined?  I suspect that it's defined in such a way that params[:id] is not defined/used.

Comment: Hi mu! i expect get the order id. because i'm on shop orders page. so, i would like to get a order and update it

Comment: Steve of couse, just a moment

Comment: do you think `oder = Oder.where(params[:id])` would work? You will need to use strong params with rails 5.  You can find info about query interface at the following link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
anyway I would like you to check the value of `params[:id]`. You can just in your controller `puts params[:id]` and in the log of your server you will see the value. If you don't see anything then params[:id] it's empty, maybe because you are not using strong params

Comment: Thank you  @FabrizioBertoglio, but i'm on rails 3

Comment: Have you checked that there is a matching record using the rails console. For example `o = Order.find(123); o.shop_id`? Have you checked if `@shop` is a valid object?